# Is there some means to increase search API quota for my project?

Tags: google-app-engine

We have some new requirements that have come up and we would like to use search API to meet those needs. The quota is too low though for loading our data. The query limit side of the quota equation would be no problem.

Is there a request mechanism in place to increase search api quota? I know it is still in experimental stage, but it seems to have been in that state for some time now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Quotas section](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview#Quotas) of the Search Api, there's a note:

> Google expects that the free quota provided during this experimental phase is sufficient for testing the experimental API. If you require additional quota please apply [here](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?pli=1&formkey=dFFJUi1GUW1mVGpOQllJUjBUOUVJUUE6MQ#gid=0).

The link is https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?pli=1&formkey=dFFJUi1GUW1mVGpOQllJUjBUOUVJUUE6MQ#gid=0

Comment: @AsafK now the SearchApi is in GA, that means that the limits explained in the question are no longer in place. You will need to enable billing if you want more quota than what's offered for free. In case you already have billing enabled and you are still hitting the lmits, then you need to be a Premier customer to request more quota. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#When_a_Resource_is_Depleted